# Getter for comboBox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, getter

I'm trying to create a getter for the comboBox in Java Swing, but I get syntaxerror. My current code:

```
public void getComboBox(String[] selections) {
    return comboBox.getSelectedItem(selections).toString();
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: By `comboBox` DYM a `JComboBox`?  Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 2):

The return type you declared is `void`, which cannot return anything.

You will need to make the return type the same as the object you are returning (in this case `String`)

```
public String getComboBox(String[] selections) {
...
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I noticed that getSelectedItem() is not suppose to take any arguments. Maybe I could try getSelectedIndex or something instead. :)

Comment: That it doesn't work does not relate to your initial question as the answer provided by Dragondraikk is the only solution providable with your given details. If satisfied with the answer of Dragondraikk, please mark this as the solution.

Comment: I only mark answers as solutions when it actually solves my problem, and this one didn't.